# Shortcut to select all content in an HTML element?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Given the following two examples:

```
<div>First Name</div>
<p>Long string of text that might even bleed off the edge of my IDE window so that I can't see it</p>
```

Is there any shortcut, modifier key, etc which I can use to select all the text within the element?

At some point I think I remember some option where if you hold CTRL and hover it will highlight entire strings? This might help but I cannot find it.

Comment: That's basically the needed action -- using it a lot. I do not remember seeing more specific/dedicated action just for that.

Comment: One partial alternative (only if you are OK to select whole tag: actual tag and its' content) -- try `Shift + Click` on breadcrumbs on that tag. Requires mouse usage .. so not great if you prefer keyboard-only operation.

Answer (score 0):

I found that "Extend Selection" (`CTRL+W`) can be used, but it is not exactly what I had in mind. Depending on what is selected already, this may take 2 or 3 presses to select the desired text.